# Term Store Management is missing from site administration section

Tags: sharepoint-server, term-store

Term Store Management is missing from site administration section. I even manually tried to go to the page by appending below but it gave an unexpected error. What are some of the reasons for this? I can see the link under another site collection under the same web application. I am also in the farm admin group and in the mms permission group

_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you a site collection administrator for the site?

Comment: Are you check if Management Metadata Service is deployed at this Farm?

Answer (score 1):

Set your account as the **site collection administrator** and then check if you can see the link or access the Term Store Management Tool.

You cannot see the link possibly because you do not have enough privilege in this site collection. But if you run into error when navigate using the URL, there is probably something wrong with the Managed Metadata Service.

You can go to Central Administration and check if the Managed Metadata Service is up and running, and if you can access the Term Store Management Tool here.

Comment: I am already in the Site collection group and as well as in the farm admin group. I can see the term store from htttp://inside.nov.com but when I got another site collection under the same web application http://inside.nov.com/sites/sales I dont see the link. MMS is up and running and I can access it from the web application's site.